# How to change an attribute value in CSS through JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
<script>
radius.style.setproperty('display');
</script>

<style>
.radius{
display: none;
}
</style>

<body>
<p id="radius"> Enter the radius</p>
</body>
```

What I intend to do here is that, by default, the paragraph has display=none. I want to display this paragraph through JS when some specific condition is met. But the problem is that using above code, I am not able to accomplish what I want. Please suggest what should have been done instead?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("radius").style.display = "block";`

and make sure to place the script after the paragraph, right before the closing tag

Comment: `.` is a class selector. You should either replace it with the id selector `#` or add a class attribute to your element.

Comment: A quick note, I think it would be nicer to control the visibility with a class: https://jsfiddle.net/km1dvtun/

Comment: Actually that's a typo here. I have used # in my original code

Comment: Just add a class that shows the element. Basic JavaScript interactions. Your CSS selector is not valid for that html element. You use a class selector, you have an id on the element.

Answer (score 0):

at the first you should get dom, after that change style attr. like this
for example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="p2">Hello World!</p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <p id="radius"> Enter the radius</p>
    


    <script>
    let radius = document.getElementById("radius");
        if(condition == true){
             radius.style.display = "block";
        }else{
             radius.style.display = "none";
             }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [element style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) in javascript

```js
element.style.cssPropertyInCamelCase = 'value'
```

Example

```js
const element = document.getElementById('id')

element.style.display = 'none'
```